Annotation And \textcite Not Interacting Well
The following is part of my document's preamble.
\usepackage[style=authoryear, citestyle=apa, hyperref=true, backend=biber, sorting=anyt]{biblatex} \addbibresource{sample.bib}

\setlength{\bibparsep}{.5\baselineskip} \renewbibmacro{finentry}{   \setunit{\finentrypunct\par}   \printfield{annotation}   \finentry}
  

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first} \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%   \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links   \bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%   \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links   \bibhyperref{%
    #1%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}}}

\savebibmacro{cite} \savebibmacro{textcite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%   \printtext[citehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{cite}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%   \ifboolexpr{
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\meaning{citecount}}{1}} )
    or
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\meaning{citecount}}{\meaning{citetotal}}} )   }
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
    {}%   \printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
    \usebibmacro{textcite}}}

However, \textcite does not come up nicely as seen in the photo:

The errors are as follows:
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   b
l.144 ...ich is why \textcite{heidegger2010being} 
                                                  calls us beings-toward-dea...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   b
l.144 ...ich is why \textcite{heidegger2010being} 
                                                  calls us beings-toward-dea...
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   b
l.144 ...ich is why \textcite{heidegger2010being} 
                                                  calls us beings-toward-dea...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> \meaning {citecount}
                               
l.144 ...ich is why \textcite{heidegger2010being} 
                                                  calls us beings-toward-dea...
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! You can't use `\numexpr' in horizontal mode.
\ifnumcomp ...\ifnum \numexpr #1\relax #2\numexpr 
                                                  #3\relax \expandafter \@fi...
l.144 ...ich is why \textcite{heidegger2010being} 
                                                  calls us beings-toward-dea...
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   b
l.144 ...ich is why \textcite{heidegger2010being} 
                                                  calls us beings-toward-dea...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   b
l.144 ...ich is why \textcite{heidegger2010being} 
                                                  calls us beings-toward-dea...
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   b
l.144 ...ich is why \textcite{heidegger2010being} 
                                                  calls us beings-toward-dea...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> \meaning {citecount}
                               
l.144 ...ich is why \textcite{heidegger2010being} 
                                                  calls us beings-toward-dea...
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! You can't use `\numexpr' in horizontal mode.
\ifnumcomp ...\ifnum \numexpr #1\relax #2\numexpr 
                                                  #3\relax \expandafter \@fi...
l.144 ...ich is why \textcite{heidegger2010being} 
                                                  calls us beings-toward-dea...
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> \meaning {citetotal}
                               
l.144 ...ich is why \textcite{heidegger2010being} 
                                                  calls us beings-toward-dea...
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

How do I fix this? Any help will be appreciated.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet compilable. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

The formatting of the code in the question is completely wrong. After putting it into correct form, the problem was quite clear:
\meaning{citecount}

is completely wrong and should be \value{citecount}.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{gonzalez,
  author       = {Gonzalez, Ray},
  title        = {The Ghost of {John Wayne} and Other Stories},
  date         = 2001,
  publisher    = {The University of Arizona Press},
  location     = {Tucson},
  isbn         = {0-816-52066-6},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sorttitle    = {Ghost of John Wayne and Other Stories},
  indextitle   = {Ghost of {John Wayne} and Other Stories, The},
  shorttitle   = {Ghost of {John Wayne}},
  annotation   = {A collection of short stories. This is a \texttt{book} entry.
                  Note the \texttt{sorttitle} and \texttt{indextitle} fields in
                  the database file. There's also an \texttt{isbn} field},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  style=authoryear,
  citestyle=apa,
  hyperref=true,
  backend=biber,
  sorting=anyt
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\setlength{\bibparsep}{.5\baselineskip}
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{%
  \setunit{\finentrypunct\par}%
  \printfield{annotation}%
  \finentry}
  
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%
  \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
  \bibhyperref{%
    #1%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}}}

\savebibmacro{cite}
\savebibmacro{textcite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[citehyperref]{%
  \restorebibmacro{cite}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} )
    or
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} )   }
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
    {}%
  \printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
    \usebibmacro{textcite}}}

\begin{document}

\textcite{gonzalez}

\printbibliography

\end{document}

I used a bib entry found in biblatex-examples.bib and filecontents* just to make the example self-contained.


That completely fixed the issue! Thank you

@KaiLe If this answer resolved your issue consider upvoting (reputation points permitting) and accepting it (by clicking the green checkmark on the top left of the answer). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. That way you show that the answer was helpful and mark the issue as resolved for you.
